# State Management in Ember application

Tags: reactjs, ember.js, redux

I am trying to compare state management solution which is present in ReactJS (using Redux or Context API/Hooks) and trying to identify a somewhat comparable thing in an Ember application.

Can Ember services (being a singleton) be termed as the state management solution in Ember application OR is there something else which can be used for state management in an Ember app ?

Comment: You can use redux in Ember https://github.com/ember-redux/ember-redux

Answer (score 11):

There are several ways Ember apps typically manage state depending on the context.

1) The URL: All state in an Ember app starts with the URL which can include query parameters as well. The URL is usually accessed via a Route and this data is transformed into something useful for the application and passed down into components.

2) The Ember Data store: For things that are persisted to storage (a database through and API for example) an Ember Data model and the accompanying store provide access to this state throughout the application. The store is a service which can be accessed from anywhere in the application and provides the same instance of a model anywhere it is requested. This means that if you change the name of a user in one place it gets reflected anywhere that user model is used.

3) Services: State which is more ephemeral that the first two can be kept in services which are injected and accessed from anywhere in the application. There are no rules for what can be placed in a service, in our app we have everything from the scroll position of a specific component to the permission of the current user.